# vba shape redraw

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

In Excel, if I add a shape to a sheet and then delete it, the shape object still remains in memory.  Is there a way to redraw that shape?  Please see the code below for reference.

```
Sub DrawTest()
    Dim x As Excel.Shape

    Set x = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLine(100, 100, 200, 200)
    Debug.Print (x Is Nothing) & " " & ObjPtr(x) 'Returns:  False 39620608

    x.Delete
    Debug.Print (x Is Nothing) & " " & ObjPtr(x)  'Returns:  False 39620608

    '
    ' Can I redraw it, at this point??    '
    '

    Set x = Nothing
    Debug.Print (x Is Nothing) & " " & ObjPtr(x)  'Returns:  True 0

End Sub
```

Comment: What makes you think the Shape is still in memory?

Comment: How about telling us wait results _you_ get from those `Debug`'s

Comment: @CindyMeister the object itself is still in memory.  As the object pointer is still returning the address.  However, it seems that it does not contain the actual shape anylonger.  I thought there may be a command to reinvoke the shape once again.

Comment: I'd say Undo is the only "hope" to get it back. If the object variable isn't set to `Nothing` then that will still be in memory. But as far as to what the developer can still access of the `Shape` - that's gone. (As far as I know, there's no way to access the "temp" and "scratch" file info where the Undo functionality stores these things.)

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you for confirming this.  Greatly apprecaited.

Comment: @marek looks like the object variable wasn't cleaned up by the delete.  So while it still points to a spot in memory, it would be unwise to assume that that memory still contains the shape data, it could have been reallocated by subsequent actions.  Also FWIW, VBA doesnt nativity support Undo, so thats probably not a useful path to follw either.  Also, could you edit the data you commented into the Q so others can easily see it?

Comment: @chris got it, thank you.  I should have done those edits like this from the getco.  my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot redraw that shape.

Also, the actual shape does not remain in memory, but the variable x is still allocating the space for that shape.

Therefore, x is still Not Nothing and, will be until you set its reference to nothing (as you did before the last Debug.Print statement)

Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Makes complete sense, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft help states that the shape.delete method is for deleting the shape.
If you want to use the shape later then the .visible =true/false might help?

Comment: I went over all this already, and I thought there may be more to it.  I guess this is the end of the road.